# Auto provisioned Lambda taking Initialization Time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, cold-start

I have a Lambda function inside a VPC to access ElasticSearch Endpoints. The Lambda has been auto provisioned (Provisioned Concurrency). The issue is, whenever the Lambda function executes, there is an Initialization time. I have set up other Lambdas without VPC setup and with auto provisioning and they do not have the cold start issue.

I [read](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/why-use-aws-lambda-in-a-custom-vpc/) about the extra time that Lambda takes when inside a VPC to initialize the ENIs and the Lambda needs to attach itself to the ENI. But the linked document doesn't mention whether the Lambda has been enabled with auto provisioning.

I wanted to know if the Lambda is inside a VPC, even if it has been enabled with Auto Provisioning, will it still take a considerable amount of Initialization time that can be seen on X-Ray Traces. Also, if this is true, is there a way to reduce this Initialization time by emitting dummy CloudWatch alerts to keep the Lambda warm?

Comment: What is "auto provision" in this context? Are you talking about Provisioned Concurrency?

Comment: Yes, it's "Provisioned Concurrency".